# AngularJS How to initialize a select using ng-options with an object value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to initialize a selection of a select field with `ng-options`.

Lets assume we've got the following items:

```
$scope.items = [{
  id: 1,
  label: 'aLabel',
  subItem: { name: 'aSubItem' }
}, {
  id: 2,
  label: 'bLabel',
  subItem: { name: 'bSubItem' }
}];
```

The following html:

```
<select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

But now instead of selecting the option by the following command:

```
$scope.selected = $scope.items[0];
```

I do not have the object, I have only the information of the id so I like to initialize the select by something like that:

```
$scope.selected = $scope.otherRandomObject.id
```

My thought was that using `track by item.id` is somehow creating the relation between object and the id.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a pre-selected value, then you can use ng-selected

```
<select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items" ng-selected="$first"></select>
```

In this case, the first item in your item array would be selected

Hope i answered your question